# How to know OS X version on startup

Tags: macos, authentication

How does one know the OS X version upon machine startup and during login? Login credentials also needed to be troubleshooted as the admin password was already forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my mac in front of me, so I am going to try to take a stab at it from memory. If you hold Command - Option - O - F you can get into something called OpenFirmware, basically the BIOS, you should be able to do it from there.

Hope that helps!

AeroVTP